# Processing - How to log Strings in txt file?

Tags: arrays, string, text-files, processing

Im getting more and more frustrated on why this is not doing what i want to. I need to have a text file that logs the last 10 buttons the user pressed, i tried in two ways but…

…this code only saves the last button pressed:

```java
String [][] buttonsPressed = { {"Pressed one"}, {"Pressed two"} };
String[] sum;

void setup() {
  size(700, 350);
  sum = loadStrings("scores.txt");
}

void draw() {
}

void keyPressed() {
  if ((key=='1')) { 
    saveStrings("scores.txt", buttonsPressed[0]);
  }

  if ((key=='2')) { 
    saveStrings("scores.txt", buttonsPressed[1]);
  }

  if ((key == ENTER)) {
    printArray(sum);
  }
}
```

…this code saves the buttons pressed but overwrites itself when i run the sketch again (probably has something to do with createWriter):

```
PrintWriter sum;

void setup() {
  size(700, 350);
  sum = createWriter("scores.txt");
}

void draw() {
}

void keyPressed() {
  if ((key=='1')) { 
    sum.println("pressed one");
  }

  if ((key=='2')) { 
    sum.println("pressed two");
  }

  if ((key == ENTER)) {
    sum.flush(); 
    sum.close();
    String[] lines = loadStrings("scores.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        printArray("[" + i + "] " + lines[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this without using libraries ? Please get me in the right direction :)

Comment: I can not provide a good answer to your question, but I found this entry in the processing forum (an old one from 2013). Maybe it can help you to solve your problem. https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/561/easiest-way-to-append-to-a-file-in-processing
I am indeed surprised that `createWriter` does not provide an append parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Break your problem down into smaller steps.

**Step 1:** At the beginning of your program, read in the existing history file. Store them in some kind of data structure, like an array or an `ArrayList.`

**Step 2:** Make the data structure keep track of the last 10 buttons pressed. You'll need to write code that adds the newest button pressed to the end of the data structure, and if the data structure contains more than 10 items, you have to remove the oldest item. Maybe do this in a separate example sketch where you just print the data structure to the console and don't worry about outputting it to a file just yet.

**Step 3:** Output the data structure to a file. You don't have to worry about appending to the file because your data structure contains the entire history, so you can just overwrite the file with the entire data structure. You'll probably want to do this every time the data structure changes. Again, maybe do this in a separate example program before worrying about where the data is coming from: maybe make a program that outputs an array of random numbers every time the user clicks?

Focus on one small step at a time, and try creating small example programs for each step. Then when you get stuck, you can ask a specific question and provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: I can not get more than 10 lines in the text file because it overwrites itself after a button is clicked.

int amountOfButtonClicks = 0;
String[][] outcomes = {{"Pressed button one"}, {"Pressed button two"}};
 
void setup() {
  //Load the items from the exsisting file
  String[] lines = loadStrings("someFile.txt");
  printArray(lines);
}

void draw() {
  if (amountOfButtonClicks >= 10){
    //remove line 11
  } 
}

void keyPressed() {
  if ((key=='1')) { 
   amountOfButtonClicks++;
   saveStrings("someFile.txt", outcomes[0]);
  }

}

How do i stop this form happening?

Comment: @Mitch_ Like I said, you need to create a data structure that keeps track of the last 10 clicks. Have you tried putting together a small example program that just does that, without worrying about outputting it to a file? Just print it to the console for now. Where are you stuck with that specific example program?

Comment: Im stuck on how i can add a string of text to an array on a keypress :(

Comment: @Mitch_ If you have a follow-up question, please post it as a new question in its own post. Don't forget the [mcve].